# PDO Blob Insert Missing Data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, blob

I'm utilizing phantom to capture images, then upload them to a centralized MySQL DB.

The issue that I'm running into is that it's consistently cutting the end off of every file I try and push.  It doesn't matter if it's .pdf, .png, .docx, .xlsx... it's cutting off part of the file, thereby corrupting it.  The weird thing is that it always cuts the same amount off each file.

My SQL insert code is:

```
$put_linkdata = $DBW->prepare('INSERT `'.$tableD.'` SET
                    captured = :capture_time,
                    error = :eYN,
                    link = :link,
                    image = :image,
                    html = :html,
                    `text` = :plaintext,
                    file = :file,
                    mimetype = :mimetype');

                $put_linkdata->bindValue(':capture_time', date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$record['timestamp']));
                $put_linkdata->bindValue(':link', $item['url']);
                $put_linkdata->bindValue(':mimetype', $record['mimetype']);
                $put_linkdata->bindParam(':eYN', $record['error'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $put_linkdata->bindParam(':image', $record_child['image'], PDO::PARAM_LOB);
                $put_linkdata->bindParam(':plaintext', $record_child['text'], PDO::PARAM_LOB);
                $put_linkdata->bindParam(':html', $record_child['html'], PDO::PARAM_LOB);
                $put_linkdata->bindParam(':file', $record_child['file'], PDO::PARAM_LOB);

                if($put_linkdata->execute()){
                    $linkData_record['id'] = $DBW->lastInsertId();
                    print PHP_EOL.mb_strlen($record_child['image'], '8bit');
                    print PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
                    die();
                }
                else{
                    throw New Exception('Error inserting linkdata record into archive - SQL error "'.$put_linkdata->queryString.'"'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.$put_linkdata->errorInfo());
                }
```

I've run a ton of tests and everything prior to here the data still maintains integrity, and if I file_put_contents() it's identical to the captured image or file.

Example of images, pulling google.com gives me a 25K image, but the upload is 17.2K.  A pdf that's 55K is uploading at 40.7K.  Another pdf is 1.5 MB, but uploads at 1.1MB.  When I diff the file against the db blob, the blob in the DB is missing content at the bottom of the file.

The size, and content isn't consistent across files, but IS consistent for identical captures.

Anyone have any ideas?

**Update**
I've narrowed it down to something happening between the prepared statement and the upload.

Also, this happens in both PDO and MySQLI when using a prepared statement.  The first assumption was that the charset encoding somewhere is incorrect, however everything is defined as UTF8 (db, table, PDO connection, config files).

Comment: my guess is that BLOB isn't big enough to hold the data. Try either MEDIUMBLOB or LONGBLOB. I've answered a similar question to this before, being just that; too small a column type.

Comment: It is actually a LONGBLOB column, but I've tried changing it to MEDIUM and BLOB to see if it had something to do with PDO and size of the blob.

Neither changes have worked, and even if it was a BLOB, 25K is still well within that range.

Comment: Is the script timing out before it finishes uploading the blob?

Comment: Nothing is timing out.  It seems to be some issue with preparing the statement before upload.  The $record_child['image'] and $record_child['file'] variables are already the same data streams as if they were file_get_contents.  As far as I'm able to tell, be it PDO or MySQLI, using a prepared query to pass any blob object to my DB is causing it to lose data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding out the issue, this post seems rather silly now, but incase anyone runs into this issue in the future...

There's an error with old versions of PHPMyAdmin where it doesn't correctly show or download data in blob columns.

Comment: Thanks lilbnyfufu for sharing your answer. I ran into a similar problem in the past. Ever since then I have stopped using Blob. Instead I upload my files to a folder and just store the file name or URL to my database. That way I know database is also returning values faster too.